# Representative Smooth Kernel Distribution from Truncated Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I am trying to produce a better distribution from a dataset that is bounded to be greater than 0. Here is an example distribution from the documentation that mimics the behavior of the actual dataset:

```
data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 10^4];
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
\[ScriptCapitalD] = TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, dist];
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x], {x, -1, 5}, PlotRange -> All,
  Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

As you can see, the peak of the SmoothKernelDistribution is not at 0, but at some value slightly greater than zero. The more points there are in the dataset, the closer the peak is to zero, as there will be a point in the dataset that is closer and closer to zero with more points. In the real dataset, I don't have the liberty of drawing more points, but I do know that the real dataset is restricted to be > 0.

Using the standard histogram, the peak will be 0 given a large enough bin size, which I guess can be achieved in SmoothKernelDistribution by increasing the kernel width, but as far as I can tell SmoothKernelDistribution does not automatically set this width to avoid the above behavior. My question is: How do I generate a SmoothKernelDistribution which mimics the behavior of the underlying distribution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of version 9 there is an undocumented extension to the kernel functions which allows you to bound the domain.  You do this by specifying the kernel function as `{"Bounded", c, ker}` where `c` is the left boundary (0 in your case) and `ker` is the usual kernel function.  You can also allow for both the left and right to be bounded via `{"Bounded", {c1, c2}, ker}`. Bounding only on the right can be done using `c1 = -Infinity`.

This works by reflecting part of the data about the boundaries and subsequently truncating the resulting estimate. As this is undocumented I make no promises that it won't someday change or that it is 100% tested.

```
data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 10^4];
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, Automatic, {"Bounded", 0, "Gaussian"}];
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[dist, x], {x, -1, 5}, PlotRange -> All,Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

To do something similar without M9 (though not in full generality) you can try reflecting the data about the y-axis and truncate yourself.

```
data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 10^4];
pseudodata = Join[-data, data];
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, 
   SmoothKernelDistribution[pseudodata]];
Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, I don't have the cajones to jump to 9 yet, so if there was a way to accomplish this in 8, that would be great.

Comment: The edit to your post is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad. You might want to use the estimate on the original data to get a better automatic bandwidth (so it isn't based on the pseudo-data).  This can be done by `SmoothKernelDistribution[data]["Bandwidth"]`.

Comment: Andy, I don't quite understand your last comment, since I've doubled the width of the distribution by reflecting it, I should use half the automatic bandwidth. `SmoothKernelDistribution[data]["Bandwidth"]` doesn't seem to work properly... **Edit:** Nevermind, I see that I need to run the SmoothKernelDistribution first on the original data, and then use the bandwidth from that.

Comment: This feature is documented (and appears to work as described) in V11