# SmoothHistogram with sharp boundary

Tags: plotting, distributions

When using [`SmoothHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothHistogram.html) (to plot probability distribution function), I noticed that the edge of the figure is automatically smoothed towards zero probability. However, in some probability distributions (or some data), this is not the case. For example,

```
SmoothHistogram[RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[1, 2], 10000]]
```

[image]

Note that at nearly zero value of x-axis, the probability distribution drops. This is incorrect. To see that, here is the result from `Histogram`, which shows correctly the sharp boundary:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[1, 2], 10000]]
```

[image]

Note that the `Histogram` plot is correct, as one can check using

```
Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[1, 2], x], {x, 0, 20}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Is it possible to tell SmoothHistogram not trying to interpolate the end points with zero?

Comment: I believe my answer to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/representative-smooth-kernel-distribution-from-truncated-distribution/15549#15549) question is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Kuba : I didn't... Why it is strange :)

Comment: @AndyRoss : Thanks a lot! Yes, this is exactly what I want. I think this question can be labelled as duplicated. Sorry I searched but haven't been able to find this post until you point out.

Comment: @Kuba I see. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The nature of the kernel smoothing process will not allow you to have a discontinuity. If you use `SmoothKernelDistribution`, then you can set the shape of the kernel used for the smoothing (`SmoothHistogram` doesn't seem to have this option). For your problem, you could choose the kernel to be (for instance) a decaying exponential and then you would be smoothing only to the right.

```
data = RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[1, 2], 10000]; d2 = 
SmoothKernelDistribution[data, Automatic, If[# > 0, Exp[-#], 0] &];
Plot[PDF[d2, x], {x, -2, 6}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, even using such a one-sided smoothing kernel does not do what you want. It fixes the problem of showing values to the left of zero (as happens with a Gaussian kernel) but will still not allow discontinuities.